# Setting child component ngModel from parent in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I have property `departureCity` in form-component (child) . When I try set it from parent calling child function it doesnt update value at DOM. I use p-autocomplete so if i call `detectChanges()` it will show my value but floating label not go up. However all work fine if I set this property in child native component

Child

```
setDepartureCityFromParent(city: SearchCity) {
    this.departureCitySuggestions = [city];
    this.departureCity = city;
  }
```

---

```
<p-autoComplete  [(ngModel)]="departureCity" [suggestions]="departureCitySuggestions" #arrivalAutoComplete
                        (completeMethod)="searchDepartureCity($event)" [forceSelection]="true" (onSelect)="setDepartureCity($event)">
```

Parent

```
 @ViewChild('citiesForm')
 citiesForm: SearchTicketsInputFormComponent;
```

---

```
this.citiesForm.setDepartureCityFromParent(city);
```

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: @Rajat I have checked it as I wrote my question (I mean without any big logic) and it works fine. Maybe it connected that I use leaflet map on this page so I have some issues with updating values both in child component and in parent component